# How to alternate HTML table row colors using JSP?

Tags: html, css, jsp, jstl

How do I alternate HTML table row colors using JSP?

My CSS looks something like:

```
tr.odd {background-color: #EEDDEE}
tr.even {background-color: #EEEEDD}
```

I want to use `<c:forEach>` to iterate over a collection.

```
<c:forEach items="${element}" var="myCollection">
  <tr>
    <td><c:out value="${element.field}"/></td>
    ...
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

I need an int count variable or boolean odd/even variable to track the row. Then my `<tr>` tag would look something like:

```
<tr class="odd or even depending on the row">
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Use the `varStatus` attribute on your `forEach` tag and JSTL will manage an instance of a [`javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagStatus`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html) for you in the variable name you specify.

You can then use a ternary operator to easily output the appropriate class name:

```
<c:forEach items="${element}" var="myCollection" varStatus="loopStatus">
  <tr class="${loopStatus.index % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
    ...
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

This [JSTL primer](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jstl0318/) from IBM has more information about the `core` tag library and what it gives you.

Answer (score 3):

Just do like this and is going to work:

```
table tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #ccc; }
```

Comment: Note: works in CSS3 aware browsers only (and thus not in IE8 and older).

Comment: A better solution in 2019.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to make this happen on the client side, you can do Zebra Striping with JQuery.

It would be done with just a couple lines of code, but you would have to include the jquery library in your file.

http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Zebra_Striping_Made_Easy

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/odd

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/even

Answer (score 2):

(this answer only pertains to the CSS side of things...)

As a matter of course, I always target the child TD's like so:

```
tr.odd td {}
tr.even td {}
```

The reason being is that IE actually applies TR background-color by removing the value set on the TR and applying it to each individual TD within that TR. Sometimes you might have a css reset or other css rules that overrides IE's strange way of doing TR background-color, so this is a way to make sure you avoid that.

Also, you might want to consider setting just

```
tr td {background-color: #EEDDEE}
```

and

```
tr.odd td {background-color: #EEEEDD}
```

so your code is slightly less verbose

Answer (score 1):

I don't use JSP, so I can't give you an answer in your language, but here's what I do (using pseudo code)

```
counter = 0
foreach (elements)
    counter = counter + 1
    output: <tr class="row{counter % 2}">...</tr>
```

Personally, I name the classes "row0" and "row1", which lets you alternate between them with a simple modulus calculation, also, if you decide to have rows alternating in triples or quads (instead of pairs), you can easily extend it to `row2`, `row3` and change your output code to be `counter % 4`, etc.

Comment: I'm really looking for the JSP syntax of how to declare the counter variable without using the <% %> tag

Answer (score 1):

I've used a tertiary operator in cases like this. It would look something like:

```
String oddEven="";
<c:forEach items="${element}" var="myCollection">
    oddEven = (oddEven == "even") ? "odd" : "even";
    <tr class='"'+oddEven+'"'>
        <td><c:out value="${element.field}"/></td>
        ...
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```