# alternating applying class to tr

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

i want to apply the css to the thr  alternatily in jsp page. below is my code.

```
<c:forEach var="aff" items="${report}">
        <tr class="**tital_black_second**">
    <input type="hidden" id="org_id" value="${aff.org_id}">
      <td width="74" class="td_text">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="173" class="heading3 td_text">${aff.string}</td>
      <td width="168" class="td_text text3">${aff.posted}</td>
      <td width="134" class="td_text text3">${aff._sold}</td>
      <td width="118" class="td_text text3">${aff.of_commision}</td>
      <td width="126" class="td_text text3">${affl}</td>
      <td width="115" class="td_text text3"></td>
      <td width="129" class="td_text text3">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

for each tr alternately i want to apply the class i.e when one tr is drawn ,i want class="tital_black_second" and when second is drawn class="tital_black_first".

How i can achieve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: take a counter , keep adding , and check the value , if odd apply class X if even apply Y

Comment: Thanks but any sample code will help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing it in jstl you can do this in CSS or jQuery.

CSS3 has a `:nth-child(arg)` pseudo-class which allows us to control the display of alternate rows. But this is only supported in modern browser, so cross-browser compatibility can be an issue with this.

```
tr:nth-child(odd)    { background-color:#ffffff; }
tr:nth-child(even)    { background-color:#000000; }
```

Or in jQuery:

```
$("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#ffffff");
$("tr:even").addClass("evenRowClass");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the solution posted here: [How to alternate HTML table row colors using JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241897/how-to-alternate-html-table-row-colors-using-jsp)

For your code it would be:

```
<c:forEach items="${report}" var="aff" varStatus="loopStatus">
  <tr class="${loopStatus.index % 2 == 0 ? 'tital_black_second' : 'tital_black_first'}">
    <input type="hidden" id="org_id" value="${aff.org_id}">
      <td width="74" class="td_text">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="173" class="heading3 td_text">${aff.string}</td>
      <td width="168" class="td_text text3">${aff.posted}</td>
      <td width="134" class="td_text text3">${aff._sold}</td>
      <td width="118" class="td_text text3">${aff.of_commision}</td>
      <td width="126" class="td_text text3">${affl}</td>
      <td width="115" class="td_text text3"></td>
      <td width="129" class="td_text text3">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [even and odd CSS rules](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd). Adding class manually to each row is unnecessary overhead.

```
.yourtable-class tr:nth-child(even) { 
   // styles for your even rows
}

.yourtable-class tr:nth-child(odd) { 
   // styles for your odd rows
}
```